# Is this a correct ripemd160 core function? (in python)

Tags: python, cryptography, ripemd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is wrong with my ripemd160 python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124165/what-is-wrong-with-my-ripemd160-python-code)

Assuming that everything else (functions, constants, etc) are correct, is this a correct main loop of ripemd160 for python?

```
for j in range(80):

   T = (a+ ROL( (F(b, c, d, j) + X[r[j]] + k[j/16])%2**32,s[j])+e)%2**32
   a = e; e = d; d = ROL(c, 10); c = b; a = T

   # parallel round
   T = (aa+ ROL( (F(bb,cc,dd,79-j) + X[rr[j]] + kk[j/16] )%2**32,ss[j])+ee)%2**32
   aa = ee; ee = dd; dd = ROL(cc,10); cc = bb; aa = T
```

Comment: You can write a test for your module based on the examples from this page: http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~bosselae/ripemd160.html

Comment: im getting nothing correct, even when i copy their code and change it to python

Comment: Don't be lazy, print out the intermediate values using both the C code and your python code. Also, pay attention to what was posted in your other question. You are still being careless with your assumptions about integers and overflow.

Comment: i have nothing to check my intermediate values with

Comment: [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) has an open source implementation of RIPEMD-160. I'm not sure if it uses the same control struture.